# Can someone face legal consequences for infecting someone else with COVID due to not following COVID regulations?

Tags: covid-19, belgium

Jurisdiction is Belgium.

Suppose a college student goes to an illegal student party and catches COVID there. He doesn't get caught by the police, he has no symptoms and he then doesn't self-isolate and goes to visit his grandmother. She is infected with COVID due to it and dies.

Could the student get charged with one of the "causing the death of another person" crimes like murder or manslaughter? And if not, Could there be any civil grounds for a lawsuit?

Bonus question: does it make any difference if the student beforehand posted a social media message stating he would be throwing parties and visiting the elderly without a mask because humans are born to socialize (actual tweet I've seen posted, though by a UK TV personality)?

Comment: Might be better to focus on one question, you're not going to get a single definitive answer for UK and belgium! some thoughts on the UK: it's definitely illegal to fail to self-isolate after being told to do so https://www.gov.uk/government/news/new-legal-duty-to-self-isolate-comes-into-force-today and people have been prosecuted for wilfully infecting people e.g. with HIV.  You didn't say if the student was formally diagnosed with the disease , even if they could be proven to have it, it would be hard to prove that they were the one who transmitted it to the grandmother.

Comment: This might help with the UK situation (note that the law in Scotland is quite different to the rest of the country with regards to Recklessness ) https://www.copfs.gov.uk/images/Documents/Prosecution_Policy_Guidance/Guidelines_and_Policy/Prosecution%20policy%20on%20the%20sexual%20transmission%20of%20infection%20-%20July%2014.pdf

Comment: Does Belgium have a law that requires *self-isolation* for the student? Here in Germany, self-isolation is a *recommendation*, but the legal status of isolation [for those who are diagnosed with a relevant infectious disease] or quarantine [for those who are suspected of having a relevant infectious disease] is legally very different and cannot be "reached" by deciding for yourself. They require a properly approbated medical doctor for the diagnosis and/or an order by the health authorities (who are currently under critique for not serving these orders in a timely manner). Some important...

Comment: ... differences: self-isolation requires you to take holidays at work, and it it is likely not accepted as an excuse for the student not showing up at their exams. Isolation / quarantine OTOH are valid reasons to not work without taking holidays and to not attend an exam. (So is a proper medical attestation that the student cannot go to work/exam)

Comment: To expand on @JeffUK's point: Proving that it was the symptomless student as opposed to the random stranger in the bus when grandma went shopping (or the equally symptomless nurse in case grandma was living in a nursing home), someone else at the doctor's, or ...  And then, grandma may have contributed to the reckless encounter as well, by insisting to hug the student, by not refusing to meet the student indoors, by not wearing an FFP mask, ...